# cannot bind array controller to a nested one to many relationship

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, data-binding, relationship

I have 3 entities in my data model which are connected as follow:
User<-->>Performance<-->>Trials

Meaning that every user has several performances, in each he/she goes under several trials.
For each entity, I have one table view and one array controller object. For all, I have bound their Managed Object Context parameter to App Delegate.

Then I bound PerformanceArrayController to UserArrayController Content Set (Controller Key: selection and performances relationship). And the same for TrialArrayController: I bound it to PerformanceArrayController (on selection) and trials relationship.

I have no problem in binding single columns of User table view and performance table view to entities attributes. but when I want to do the same for trial table view, first I don't get autocompletion and second when I write the name of the attributes manually, **I get a gray exclamation mark. and only the first trial is saved this way but not the rest of them.**

Here is my function for inserting into Trial:

```
    - (void) insertIntoTrial: (NSString *) result
    {
      NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
      NSError *error;

      Trial *trial = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trial" inManagedObjectContext:context];
      trial.result = result;
      trial.time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[cueTimestamp timeElapsedInSeconds]];

      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Performance" inManagedObjectContext:context];
      [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
      [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.fName==%@", userName]];
      NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

      for (Performance *performance in fetchedObjects) {
        [performance addTrialsObject:trial];
        trial.performance = performance;
      }

      if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't save Trial info: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }

    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I've had the same issue a couple of times, and the app still runs as expected.

Comment: Did you set the entity property of the array controllers correctly (Copy & paste …)? Does insertion works (via the array controllers)?

Comment: the name of entity properties are fine. but I'd never tried insertion for trials and when you suggested, I tried: it doesn't work and I get this exception: "[__NSCFDictionary managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
I guess now that I should not use one managedobjectcontext which is defined in appDelegate for all of these arrayControllers. but then I don't know how should I solve it.

Comment: (I used to insert through the code and not using array controller. but then I couldn't see anything in trials table view.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I just edited my post. I actually do not need to add trials data manually or by button press, etc. it has to be automatic and I just posted my function code for it. But more accurately my problem is that only the first trial is saved and not the rest tries.
thanks